# Initialize numeric struct fields with char array in C?

Tags: arrays, c, struct, initialization

Let's say I'm creating a struct with mostly numeric fields. Then, I'd like to initialize these different fields with values that are ASCII chars, so that in the end, I could cast the struct as a `char*` pointer, and print it in one go, and obtain a sort of a per-byte "map" printout of the struct.

I came to the following example that compiles:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

struct mystruct_s {
  uint8_t id_tag[6]; 
  uint8_t fld_one[2];
  uint64_t fld_two;
  uint16_t fld_three;
  uint16_t fld_four;
  uint16_t fld_five;
};

struct mystruct_s myrh = {
  .id_tag = "123456",
  .fld_one = "78",
  .fld_two = (uint64_t) ((uint8_t[8]) { 'T', 'T', 'T', 'T', 'T', 'T', 'T', 'T' }),
};

int main() {
  printf("size %zu (%zu) bytes\n", sizeof(myrh), sizeof(struct mystruct_s));
  printf("as string:\n");
  printf("%s\n", (char*)&myrh);
  printf("char 10: '%c'\n", ((char*)&myrh)[9]);
  return 0;
}
```

... however, when it runs, it produces:

```
$ gcc -g main.c -o main.exe
$ ./main.exe
size 24 (24) bytes
as string:
12345678`�V
char 10: ''
```

... whereas I would have expected something like `12345678TTTTTTT` (and char 10 being also 'T'). So, clearly my "cast" did not quite work.

So, is there some sort of syntax, where I could initialize a numeric field of a struct, with the values equivalent to a char array? (Note, the above example shows the intent to initialize all bytes in .fld_two to 'T', that is, 0x54 as per ASCII - but I'm ultimately interested in specifying arbitrary strings like this, with varying characters)

---

Second thing that I found surprising, is that if I add another field initialization:

```c
...
struct mystruct_s myrh = {
  .id_tag = "123456",
  .fld_one = "78",
  .fld_two = (uint64_t) ((uint8_t[8]) { 'T', 'T', 'T', 'T', 'T', 'T', 'T', 'T' }),
  .fld_three = (uint16_t) ((uint8_t[2]) { 'E', 'E' }),
};
...
```

... then building fails with:

```
gcc -g main.c -o main.exe
main.c:18:16: warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size [-Wpointer-to-int-cast]
   .fld_three = (uint16_t) ((uint8_t[2]) { 'E', 'E' }),
                ^
main.c:18:16: error: initializer element is not constant
main.c:18:16: note: (near initialization for ‘myrh.fld_three’)
```

So, how come it did NOT detect an error on this line:

```
.fld_two = (uint64_t) ((uint8_t[8]) { 'T', 'T', 'T', 'T', 'T', 'T', 'T', 'T' }),
```

... and yet it *did* find an error on this line:

```
 .fld_three = (uint16_t) ((uint8_t[2]) { 'E', 'E' }),
```

... even if both lines are apparently doing the same thing, just with different sizes and values?

Comment: Do you realize "78" is 3 bytes?

Comment: Also, you might read about `__packed__`. Correct me if I'm wrong, but I believe printing whole structure probably will lead to undefined behavior, even if it's packed.

Comment: @AndrejsCainikovs Yes I do - I deliberately defined the fld_one as two characters, so the last '\0' from the string spec would be "dropped", and so I'd get a concatenated string, same for id_tag (seems C compiler tolerates this, eg. id_tag[6] = "123456", the same with id_tag[5] will not compile)

Comment: @AndrejsCainikovs - you're absolutely right about `__packed__`, I forgot about those holes; anyways, I tried to pay attention that at least all fields have even amount of bytes - on some platforms, I get uint16_t alignment. But, let's assume the above example struct was "packed" so no problems arising due to holes - is there a way to initialize data in structs through "textual strings"?

Comment: The result of `((uint8_t[8]) { 'T', 'T', 'T', 'T', 'T', 'T', 'T', 'T' })` and `((uint8_t[2]) { 'E', 'E' })` are pointers, so the contents is not as you expect and casting to 16 bit gives the observed warning because the pointer value is truncated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`(uint64_t) ((uint8_t[8]) { 'T', 'T', 'T', 'T', 'T', 'T', 'T', 'T' })`

This creates a *compound literal* at the same scope as where it is used. Like any array, the `uint8_t [8]` decays into a pointer to the first element when used in an expression. So you end up casting *an address* to `uint64_t`, not the data.

You can solve this with union type punning. Something like:

```c
typedef union
{
  uint8_t  bytes [8];
  uint64_t u64;
} pun_intended;

...

.fld_two = (pun_intended){ .bytes = {'T', 'T', 'T', 'T', 'T', 'T', 'T', 'T'} }.u64,
```

However that brings another problem, namely that it is no longer a compile-time constant expression. Which should of course ideally be solved by not using sloppy globals in the first place. But in case that is not an option (maybe you need `const`), you could alternatively change the type of the struct member:

```c
pun_intended fld_two;
...
.fld_two = (pun_intended){ .bytes = {'T', 'T', 'T', 'T', 'T', 'T', 'T', 'T'} },
```

Comment: Many thanks  @Lundin - I am usually aware about "decays into a pointer" part, but somehow I didn't even think of it when I started the OP; thanks for noticing and correcting! Also, was not aware of union punning, looks like a good approach  (although still a bit too much typing for the kind of a quick overview that I wanted to use this for :) )

Answer (score 0):

Well, I sort of managed to do the effect I desired via unions - but there is so much typing and boilerplate, it defeats the purpose (I wanted the syntax in the OP because it appears easy :) )

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

struct mystruct_s {
  uint8_t id_tag[6]; 
  uint8_t fld_one[2];
  uint64_t fld_two;
  uint16_t fld_three;
  uint16_t fld_four;
  uint16_t fld_five;
} __attribute__((packed));
struct mystruct_alt_s {
  unsigned char id_tag[6]; 
  unsigned char fld_one[2];
  unsigned char fld_two[8];
  unsigned char fld_three[2];
  unsigned char fld_four[2];
  unsigned char fld_five[2];
} __attribute__((packed));

union undata {
  struct mystruct_alt_s myo_alt;
  struct mystruct_s myo;
} ;

union undata data = {
  .myo_alt = {
    .id_tag = "123456",
    .fld_one = "78",
    .fld_two = "TTTTTTTT",
    .fld_three = "HH",
    .fld_four = "RR",
    .fld_five = "VV",
  }
};


int main() {
  printf("size %zu (%zu) bytes\n", sizeof(data), sizeof(struct mystruct_s));
  printf("as string:\n");
  printf("%s\n", (char*)&data.myo);
  return 0;
}
```

This prints:

```
$ gcc -g main.c -o main.exe
$ ./main.exe
size 22 (22) bytes
as string:
12345678TTTTTTTTHHRRVV
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to your own answer, you may use the newly learned X Macros to gather the variable definitions and initialization strings in one place:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

// X macro taking Type, Name, Count, ValueString
#define FIELDS \
  X(uint8_t, id_tag, [6], "123456") \
  X(uint8_t, fld_one, [2], "78") \
  X(uint64_t, fld_two, , "TTTTTTTT") \
  X(uint16_t, fld_three, , "HH") \
  X(uint16_t, fld_four, , "RR") \
  X(uint16_t, fld_five, , "VV")

#define X(T,N,C,V) T N C;
struct mystruct_s {
  FIELDS
} __attribute__((packed));
#undef X

#define X(T,N,C,V) unsigned char N[sizeof(T C)];
struct mystruct_alt_s {
  FIELDS
} __attribute__((packed));
#undef X

union undata {
  struct mystruct_alt_s myo_alt;
  struct mystruct_s myo;
} ;

#define X(T,N,C,V) .N = V,
union undata data = {
  .myo_alt = {
    FIELDS
  }
};
#undef X

int main() {
  printf("size %zu (%zu) bytes\n", sizeof(data), sizeof(struct mystruct_s));
  printf("as string:\n");
  printf("%s\n", (char*)&data.myo);
  return 0;
}
```